# LinkIt: transform content

Tags: link

As Craft doesn't provide an all-in-one link field (that covers external as well as internal links) out of the box, I opted for LinkIt.

What I wonder, how do I

- Obfuscate email-links?
- Bring phone numbers to a working format, by removing whitespace and adding the + in the right spot?

I expected LinkIt would do that by itself, but I haven't seen where yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not super familiar the LinkIt, but there is a feature request for email obfuscation here: https://github.com/fruitstudios/craft-linkit/issues/58 you can comment on and you can make a new one for phone numbers.

In the meantime, some other plugins might do what you're looking for:

https://plugins.craftcms.com/obfuscator

https://plugins.craftcms.com/phone-number

Or you could make your own custom link types: https://github.com/fruitstudios/craft-linkit#custom-link-types

Comment: Thanks Brad! I've knocked there https://github.com/fruitstudios/craft-linkit/issues/74